# How do I use formtastic to create a remote form using acts_as_commentable in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic, acts-as-commentable

I am using acts_as_commentable.  This is how the Model has comments added to it:

```
 commentable = Post.create
 commentable.comments.create(:title => "First comment.", :comment => "This is the first comment.")
```

the gem specifics can be found here:

https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

In formtastic, I normally would pass the model, and then the input fields....would that still work?

```
 <%= semantic_form_form 'review' do |form| %>

     <%= form.input :title %>
     <%= form.input :comment %>
 <% end %>
```

And in the controller....?

```
  commentable.comments.create(params(:review))
```

I'm not sure if this would pass the hash that is usable....thanks!

Comment: oh yeah, I guess I want it to submit remote....as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work. Did you try it?

Just like Rails' `form_for`, you can pass in a `:remote => true` option for remote forms.